# Convert iOS developer account from individual to company

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-developer-program

I have enrolled my apple account as Individual for iOS development program. Now I wish to convert it into Company/Organisation account. I have searched online but couldn't find any way to do this. Is it possible to convert it or should I create new apple account for enrolling as Company/Organisation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you did through the "Resources and Help" page on iTunes Connect? And the FAQ on iTunes Connect?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a support issue with a developer account and not a programming question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From apple's [Program Enrollment support page](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.php):

> If you have enrolled as an individual and need to convert your individual account to a company account, please [contact us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php).

Comment: How many days it takes to convert the account from Individual to Company?